# Getting error when exporting Azure SQL database using az cli?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cli

I am getting an error when i try to export an Azure sql database . I am using the folowing to export :

```
    az sql db export -s pds1 -n pdb1 -g resourcegroup --admin-password "password" --admin-user "username" --auth-type ADPassword --storage-key accesskey --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri "storage accname.blob.core.windows.net/folder1/myBacpac.bacpac"
```

The error is :

> Message: The ImportExport operation failed due to 'An error occurred while communicating with the SQL Server using AdPassword-login: Could not discover a user realm.',

Any ideas on this ?

Update :

```
   CREATE USER [testuser] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;

   ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [testuser];
   ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [testuser];
   ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [testuser];
```

Comment: I see other users complaining about the same on this thread https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/569781/unable-to-export-a-dataase-from-an-azure-sql-insta. Verify the account does not have MFA because is not supported by the export service. Verify the account has the "SQL DB Contributor" RBAC role

Comment: so i assume the user must be a user on the db and be a contributor ? Cant i create a user using what i put in the question under update

Comment: I have verified that the user has SQL DB Contributor" RBAC role and does not have MFA. When i export from Azure Portal it works . So from the portal before i do the export can i some how get the powershell script it uses or can i somehow use the export template in powershell ?

Comment: I used to use the script provided on this article but is no longer working https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/automate-exporting-of-azure-sql-database-as-bacpac-to-blog/ba-p/2409213. With Azure CLI I have not been able to make it work

Comment: Are you willing to use a Managed Identity along with Azure CLI?

Answer (score 0):

> Message: The ImportExport operation failed due to 'An error occurred while communicating with the SQL Server using AdPassword-login: Could not discover a user realm.',

There is certain limitation while using Microsoft Entra Id authentication (Azure Ad authentication).

As per this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export?view=azuresql#considerations)

> - ***The Import/Export service does not support Microsoft Entra ID authentication when MFA is required.***
> - ***Import\Export services only support SQL authentication and Microsoft Entra ID. Import\Export is not compatible with Microsoft Identity application registration (service principal)***

As per documented [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/) Only native and integrated domain Azure AD accounts are currently supported for Azure SQL DB connection.

**Either use valid native or integrated domain user for authentication or use the admin user to authenticate**

User should be of **member** type you can see it under Microsoft Entra ID >> users as below:
[image]